# What are those blue stripes or patches on Balotelli's back?

Tags: football, equipment, euro

I've seen a lot of players with those blue stripes or patches like Balotelli wore in the Italy - Germany Euro 2012 semi-final:

[image: Balotelli celebrate Euro 2012 semi-final goal]

What are those stripes / patches/ tapes?

Comment: **Welcome** to those of you who are here for the first time! Please note that while anyone may freely answer, answers like "Neat!" or "I had the same question, thanks for this!" **are subject to immediate deletion.** This is what keeps our quality high. If you're curious and want to know more, have a look at our [faq].

Comment: The BBC have ran an article on this tape: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-18672458

Comment: @Ste We were first!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is [Kinesio Tape](http://www.kinesiotaping.co.uk/), which is an [adhesive-tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_therapeutic_tape) that is applied to problematic muscles.

Problematic as in, the muscles are weak after returning from injury (you can support them using Kinesio tape), or you can apply it to aching muscles to sooth the pain. It's application can also increase blood flow to the muscles, and speed up the recovery process.

Specifically to Mario, [no-one knows](http://www.ministryofsoccer.org/2012/06/what-is-the-blue-kinesio-tape-on-soccer-players/) the exact reason he's using it.

[Here's an article](http://www.physioroom.com/products/kinesio_tape.php) which explains the science behind it (beyond me :P).